# Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last content on the line

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, psr-3

I Write this code in my PHP file :

```
public function ScriptsStyles()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'fontawesome', 
            plugins_url("/css/font-awesome.css", __FILE__), 
            array(),
            'null' 
        );

        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'base', 
            plugins_url("/css/base.css", __FILE__), 
            array('fontawesome'), 
            'null' 
        );

        wp_enqueue_script(
            'main', 
            plugins_url("/js/main.js", __FILE__), 
            array('test') 
        );

        wp_enqueue_script(
            'test', 
            plugins_url("/js/test.js", __FILE__), 
            array('jquery') 
        );

    }
```

And when I checked it, using PHP Code Sniffer I get this Errors :

> Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last
>   content on the line

those errors comes from  this lines:

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 
                    'fontawesome', 
                    plugins_url("/css/font-awesome.css", __FILE__), 
                    array(),
                    'null' 
                );

  wp_enqueue_style( 
                    'base', 
                    plugins_url("/css/base.css", __FILE__), 
                    array('fontawesome'), 
                    'null' 
                );
```

How to fix that ? And thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You have a space at the end of your line. :)**

It expects the line to end in `(` but it ends in `[space]`.