# Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last content

Tags: php

I have been receiving a PHP Code Sniffer error relating to line 7 in the code below.

Moving the next square open bracket to this line seems to introduce new errors.  I'm a little unclear as to how to resolve this.

> Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last content

```
if ($cms_user) {
    array_push($buttons, [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Home Page'
    ]);
} elseif ($public) {
    array_push($buttons,
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'About Us'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 11,
            'name' => 'Reflection',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Contact Us',
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last content on the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131095/opening-parenthesis-of-a-multi-line-function-call-must-be-the-last-content-on-th)

Comment: I'm afraid not, I already referenced that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Opening parenthesis of a multi-line function call must be the last
>   content

If you have a function that spans more than one line, then the opening paren of the function call must be the last thing on the first line. I usually do something like this:

```
array_push(
    $buttons,
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Home Page'
    ]
);
```

Comment: Perfect, this fixed it! Thanks